# Materializecss with jquery validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, materialize

HTML markup;

```
<div id="address" class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
        <form method="post" action="" id="addressDetails">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <textarea id="lAddress" name = 'lAddress' minlength='20' maxlength='100' class="materialize-textarea" class="validate" required length="100"></textarea>
                <label for="lAddress" data-error="Must be between 20 to 100 Characters">Local Address</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <textarea id="pAddress" name = 'pAddress' minlength='20' maxlength='100' class="materialize-textarea" class="validate" required length="100"></textarea>
                <label for="pAddress" data-error="Must be between 20 to 100 Characters">Permanent Address</label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row center-align">
        <button type="submit" name="submitAddress" form="addressDetails" class="waves-effect waves-light light-blue darken-1 btn updateProfile">Save Address Details</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function updateProfile(event) {
    console.log(this);
    event.preventDefault();
    form = $(this).closest('.col.s12').find('form');
    $.ajax('profile/updateProfile.php', {
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            Materialize.toast(result.message, 4000);
        },
        error: function() {
            Materialize.toast("Failed: Please contact admin.", 4000);
        },
        timeout: 5000
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button.updateProfile").on('click', updateProfile);
});
```

Earlier with normal form submission validation was working. But now with jQuery AJAX request I am able to send data, but when form is invalid then it shows error in red but it accepts the form with error.

When I am using `$("button.updateProfile").on('sumbit', updateProfile);` it is validating but it is reloading the page and preventDefault is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("button.updateProfile").on('click', updateProfile);`

This will not validate with the help of materialize validate. You have to look for `submit`.

Again with submit it will have problem, it is not looking for submission in form.

`$("button.updateProfile").on('sumbit', updateProfile);`

Instead of button use form, then will look for form submission. Like this

`$("form").on('submit', updateProfile);`

This will work perfectly.

So remember whenever you are submitting a form check for submit on form not on submit buttons.